# Pass parameter from keyword on robot framework

Tags: python, robotframework

I am new on python and robot framework. Previously, I use ruby as testing, and I oftenly use this

```
feature file:

Scenario : User can open browser
 User opens browser using "Chrome"


rb file:

And (/^User opens browser using "(.*)" $/) do |browser|{
   //open browser step
}
```

but when i try similar step on python like this

```
*Keyword*
User opens browser using ${browser}
  IF ${browser} == Chrome
  open browser  chrome
  ELSE
  open browser  firefox
  END

*Test Cases*
User should be able to open page with browser
   User opens browser using chrome
```

I got response
No keyword with name 'User opens browser using chrome' found.

Can you help me guys? Or maybe there will be no clue to create similar steps on python robot framework? Thank you in advance

Comment: not that it matters now but you pass "chrome" but expect "Chrome". This alone however does not explain the error response

Comment: can you share your whole robot file?

Comment: The code you posted can't give the error you say it does because you have some syntax errors. Are you certain _this_ code produces `No keyword with name...`?

Answer (score 0):

you need to send the ${browser} as a argument to the keyword like:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Open User Browser   ${browser}

***Keywords***
Open User Browser
[Arguments]   ${inputVar}   # this variable can be called anything
   IF   '''${inputVar}''' == '''Chrome'''
      open browser   chrome
   ELSE
      open browser   firefox
   END
```

Comment: embedding arguments is alowed in RF look [here](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#toc-entry-333), maybe share some more information on how this helps

Comment: The way he described his solution what he wants is a argument and not having separate keywords for all the combinations of the variable value.
also, in that particular case of embedding the variable, if he doesn't control the input values then he is going to have issues when a non defined value -> keyword is not present.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like some spacing is incorrect but it's difficult to know whether that's from copying into here. However it is possible to use embedded arguments within keywords and I can give you an example.

A couple of other things to note

1. The IF statement is a bit redundant as you can pretty much pass the variable Firefox or Chrome directly to the Open Browser paramter and make it a bit cleaner.
2. You can be strict on the embedded variables if you wish to by specifying them as different options as per example below
3. Open Browser usually takes url first - if you're not specifiying url then you may need to use named arg afaik

   ```
    *** Settings ***
    Library  SeleniumLibrary
    Test Teardown  Close Browser

    *** Test Cases ***
    User should be able to open page with browser
        User opens the chrome browser

    User tries to open an alternative browser
        User opens the firefox browser

    User tries to open browser not supported by keyword 
        User opens the ie browser  # Fails

    *** Keywords ***
    user opens the ${browser:(chrome|Chrome|firefox|Firefox)} browser
        Open Browser  browser=${browser}
   ```

Both "Chrome" and "chrome" will work with Open Browser without switching capitilization though if you wanted to you could convert to lowercase before sending to open browser (Uses String library)

```
*** Keywords ***
user opens the ${browser:(chrome|Chrome|firefox|Firefox)} browser
    ${browser_lowercase}  Convert To Lowercase  ${browser}
    Open Browser  browser=${browser_lowercase}
```

An alternative which is truer to your original is to embed some regex which can make certain parts of the keyword optional and allow keyword to have a browser specified as optional. In the example below I've made it so adding the "using" part of the keyword is option so when the keyword is used without a browser specified, it still reads correctly and the logic if browser variable has not been set to default to Firefox:

```
*** Settings ***
Library  SeleniumLibrary
Test Teardown  Close Browser

*** Test Cases ***
Scenario: Test1 - Open Chrome Browser
    User opens browser using Chrome

Scenario: Test2 - Open Firefox Browser
    User opens browser

*** Keywords ***
User opens browser${r:( using )?}${browser:(.*)}        
    IF  "${browser}"!="${EMPTY}"
        Open Browser  browser=${browser}
    ELSE 
        Open Browser  browser=firefox
    END
```

Answer (score 0):

I am having the versions of robot framework and python as shown:
Robot Framework 5.0.1 (Python 3.10.7 on win32)

My test case is as shown:

*** Keywords ***

TC_Keyword_${num}

```
Log  Inside the TC_Keyword_${num}
```

*** Test Cases ***

TC1

```
TC_Keyword_chrome

TC_Keyword_${2}
```

The output is as shown:

[image]